# jquery calendar pull information from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a jquery calendar and I want to populate this with data from mysql database, my php script works on its own i.e displays data correctly however I am struggling to get this to work with the calendar script. Any ideas anyone?

Here's my code;-

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y/m/d");?>',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-11-16T16:00:00'
            },

            {
                title: 'name',
                start: '2015-04-27',
                end:   '2015-04-29',
            },

            {
                title: 'Michael',
                start: '2015-04-27',
                end:   '2015-04-27',
            },
            {
                title: 'Matthew',
                start: '2015-04-27',
                end:   '2015-05-01',
            },
            {
                title: 'Eric',
                start: '2015-05-04',
                end:   '2015-05-08',
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

```
php include('../include/connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidays ORDER BY id DESC");
or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

echo "  {   title:'" . $row['title'] . "',";
echo "      start:'" . $row['start'] . "',";
echo "      end:'" . $row['end'] . "'},";
 }
```

Comment: Don't create json by yourself, use json_encode function instead : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: thanks xNeyte - I do not fully understand json yet, could you explain more specifically how I would approach this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `events` as json feed. [click for docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

**JS:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'//place url to your php script here.
});
```

**PHP:**

```
php include('../include/connect.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM holidays ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
$events = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $events[] = array(
                    "title" => $row['title'],
                    "start" => $row['start'],
                    "end" => $row['end']
                );
 }
echo json_encode($events);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using mysql methods, it is deprecated now, go for PDO or mysqli methods instead.

I think your ORDER BY id is pretty useless in this case since it will just load all events, we don't really care how it is sorted

To create json, it will be like this :

```
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      array_push($json, array("title" => $row['title'],
                              "start" => $row['start'],
                              "end" => $row['end']));
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

And in your fullcalendar folder, you have an example to load events from JSON if I well remember